# How to join two tables - Get a count - As well as show max date

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

sorry I have no clue on how to do this.

Here is some sample data.

```
Data                    Data Entry          
Name    Active  key     Name    Active  Date    key
Name 1  1       1       Name 1  1       Jan-15  1
Name 2  0       2       Name 2  1       Feb-15  2
Name 3  1       3       Name 1  1       Jan-14  1
Name 4  1       4       Name 3  1       Feb-15  3
Name 5  1       5       Name 3  0       Jan-14  3
Name 6  0       6       Name 4  1       Feb-15  4
Name 7  1       7       Name 5  1       Mar-15  5
Name 8  1       8       Name 6  1       Apr-15  6
```

Two tables Data , and Data_Entry you can say.

How do I get an output from this where it shows.

data.active = '1' and data_entry.active = '1' for each key ? as well as the count that it shows up in the data_entry

I would want the output to be for example this : As it is only showing me active data that has an active entry in the data_entry table and the count to be only that of active entries from data_entry

```
name     last_date    count
name 1   Jan-15       2
name 3   Feb-15       1
name 4   Feb-15       1
Name 5   Mar-15       1
Name 6   Apr-15       1
```

Comment: Looks like a simple aggregation. What seems to be a problem? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: You need to `FROM data A  INNER JOIN [data entry] B on A.key=B.Key`  And `select A.Name, max(b.date) as last_date, count(B.date) as count` and lastly `Group by A.Name`

Answer (score 0):

I think that should work for you:

```
SELECT
    name,
    MAX(date) AS last_date,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT
        data.key
        data.name,
        data_entry.key,
        data_entry.date
    FROM data
    INNER JOIN data_entry ON data_entry.key = data.key
    WHERE data.active = 1 AND data_entry.active = 1
) subquery
GROUP BY key, name
```